# POST User information from Front End to MongoDB backend React-Native, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, post, axios

I have a simple Android login system and a mongoDB & Express coupled with it. The front end has some input fields, with which i have implemented redux to access the variable in all pages of the system. Im having trouble posting user information from the front end fields to the database through the backend that i have.

I need to know eaxactly how to post that data from my frontend to the mongoose database that i have. Below is my code.

The form

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
> import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
> import InputText from './InputText';
> import { connect } from 'react-redux';
> import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
> import {updatePlates, updateNumber} from '../actions/user';
>
> const styles =StyleSheet.create({
>   container : {
>     padding:-10,
>     flex: 1,
>     alignItems: 'center',
>     justifyContent:'center'
>   },
>   textDesign:{
>     fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
>     width: 300,
>     elevation: 10,
>     padding: 10,
>     backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
>     borderRadius: 20,
>     marginVertical: 20,
>     fontSize: 15,
>   }
> });
>
>
> class Form extends Component{
>   //<Text style={styles.txt}>Home: {this.props.user.email}</Text>
>   render(){
>     return(
>       <View style={styles.container}>
>       <TextInput placeholder="Car Registration Plates"
>           style={styles.textDesign}
>           placeholderTextColor = '#878080'
>           value={this.props.user.plates}
>           onChangeText={input => this.props.updatePlates(input)}
>         //  underlineColorAndroid='rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)'
>       />
>       <TextInput placeholder="Mobile Number"
>           style={styles.textDesign}
>           placeholderTextColor = "#878080"
>           value={this.props.user.number}
>           onChangeText={input => this.props.updateNumber(input)}
>       />
>       </View>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
>   return bindActionCreators({updatePlates, updateNumber},dispatch)
> }
>
> const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
>   return {
>     user: state.user
>   }
> }
>
>
> export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps )(Form)
> ```

The  post method

```
router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const userData= {
    phone: String( req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g, ''),
    car: req.body.contact_number
  }

  const user= new User(userData);

  user.save().then((user) =>{
    if(user){
    return user.generateAuthToken();
    } else{
      res.sendStatus(400);
    }
  }).then((token) =>{
    res.header({'x-auth': token}).send(user)
  }).catch((error) =>{
    res.status(400).send(error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem you want to have a side effect in your action. So you need to use a middleware in your application either redux thunk middle ware or redux saga.

Create an action for the submission of data from your component. From this action call the side effect function and update the state to let the component that action is success or not.

Action creator

```
function postData(dispatch, data) { // needs to dispatch, so it is first argument
  return dispatch=> fetch("api/postdata",
    {
        body: data,
        method: "post"
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      data => dispatch({ type: 'POST_DATA_SUCCESS', data }),
      err => dispatch({ type: 'POST_DATA_FAILURE', err })
    );
}
```

in your component  on submission

`postData(this.props.dispatch, data);`  // don't forget to pass dispatch